# ERROR Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, linq, dto

I have the stored procedures in sql server to insert a user but i'm getting this error when trying to map the sp with a DTO class I have.

```
DataClasses1DataContext _dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();

public List<WebUserDTO> InsertUser (string Username, string UserPassword, string FullName, string Email)
    {
        var user = _dataContext.WebUser_InsertUser(Username, UserPassword, FullName, Email);
        return user.Select(aux => new WebUserDTO()
        {
            UserName = aux.Username,
            UserPassword = aux.UserPassword,
            FullName = aux.FullName,
            Email = aux.Email
        }).ToList();
    }
```

Error shows here: `var user = _dataContext.WebUser_InsertUser(Username, UserPassword, FullName, Email);`
My Insert sps are the following and I have correct results when executing `dbo.WebUser_InsertUser` in sql server

```
CREATE PROC dbo.WebUser_InsertUser0
    @Username AS NVARCHAR (20),
    @UserPassword AS NVARCHAR (20),
    @FullName AS NVARCHAR (50),
    @Email AS NVARCHAR (50),
    @IdUser AS INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.WebUser (UserName, UserPassword, FullName, Email)
VALUES (@UserName, @UserPassword, @FullName, @Email)
SET @IdUser = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN @IdUser;
END
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.WebUser_InsertUser
    @Username1 AS NVARCHAR (20),
    @UserPassword1 AS NVARCHAR (20),
    @FullName1 AS NVARCHAR (50),
    @Email1 AS NVARCHAR (50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE
    @UserId1 AS INT
EXEC dbo.WebUser_InsertUser @UserName1, @UserPassword1, @FullName1, @Email1, @UserId1 OUT
SELECT W.IdUser, W.UserTypeId, W.Username, W.UserPassword, W.FullName, W.Email
FROM dbo.WebUser AS W
WHERE W.IdUser = @UserId1
RETURN;
END
```

Comment: Can you post more of the surrounding code? Also, have a look here.            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814302/cannot-assign-void-to-an-implicitly-typed-local-variable-with-var-and-foreach

Comment: The type of a var must be impliable from context. Just becaue you do not type out the type name, does not mean that the Compiler will at any time stop to do typechecks! If you want to get rid of compile time typechecks, use dynamic (or better change your design so you do not have too). The propblem is propably that WebUser_InsertUser returns void (or at elast one overload does). Without knowing details of that class, that is the best guess I got.

Comment: What is the return type of `var user = _dataContext.WebUser_InsertUser` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you need something like that:

```
public List<WebUserDTO> InsertUser (string Username, string UserPassword, string FullName, string Email)
{
    _dataContext.WebUser_InsertUser(Username, UserPassword, FullName, Email);
    // since you did not provide _dataContext type definition
    // I can only guess how your user collection is called in your DbContext.
    return _dataContext.users.Select(aux => new WebUserDTO()
    {
        UserName = aux.Username,
        UserPassword = aux.UserPassword,
        FullName = aux.FullName,
        Email = aux.Email
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally worked, the problem was the return type of my stored procedure I was able to change it to WebUser from the designer